# for loop over a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a function **ask_phone_number()** defined and a **for** loop inside the function. I want the for loop to iterate over a list *(the list contains **1** string of characters)*. I have an **elif** statement in the for loop for **counting the number of characters of the string in phone_number,** but its returning 1 as the count. I guess this is happening because python interpreter sees the string itself as the only item in my list. My question is **how can I tell python to count the characters of the string in phone_number list** and not just the item in phone_number"
*PLEASE SEE CODE BELOW:*

```
def ask_phone_number(correct, phone_number):
    while correct == False:
        phone_number = [input("Enter your phone number >>> ")]
        for ch in phone_number:
            if ("+1" not in ch):
                print("Make sure to enter '+1' and your 10 digit US or Canada phone number")
            elif (phone_number.count(ch) < 12):
                print("Your phone number is incomplete")
            else:
                correct = True
    else:
        return phone_number


if __name__ == "__main__"
   ask_phone_number(False, "")
```

Comment: For testing and debugging, please hard-code the "input". Or else please [edit] your question to show us the actual input.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your function takes two parameters but you call it without any, so this can not possibly represent the code you're having issues with.

Comment: Even after your edit, the code isn't runnable. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @Ulrich I've fixed the arguments in the function call...just a silly error

Comment: Is there any situation where you would pass different values to this function? Like `ask_phone_number(True, "+143765876912")`? Trying to understand why you have these parameters...

Comment: elif len(ch) < 12:
should work for what you're trying to do

Comment: Please copy above code into a file and run it. That's still not a [mcve]. That said, why are you passing these arguments to the function at all? What is their meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your code creates `phone_number` as a list. Drop the square brackets.
- Once the above is fixed, your loop takes every character in the phone number and then counts how many times *that* character occurs in the phone number. So that will be at least 1 (because you took that character from it), but has obviously nothing to do with the number of digits in the phone number.
- I don't see the utility to pass `correct` and `phone_number` as argument. The goal of the function is to ask the user for the phone number, so it should not be an argument. And whether it is correct or not is up to the function to determine, not an argument.

So:

```
def ask_phone_number():
    while True:
        phone_number = input("Enter your phone number >>> ")
        if not phone_number.startswith("+1"):
            print("Make sure to enter '+1' and your 10 digit US or Canada phone number")
        elif len(phone_number) < 12:
            print("Your phone number is incomplete")
        else:
            return phone_number
```

Comment: much appreciated insights @trincot

Answer (score 0):

```
phone_number.count(ch)
```

counts the number of times the string ch is in the list phone_number. This is always 1.
You should use

```
elif len(ch) < 12:
```

Comment: thanks @randomer64...it worked perfectly

Comment: I'm glad it works and if you mark it as right/helpful answer, it would make me even happier!